# How to insert values from an array into select json keys

Tags: json, node.js, backend

I have this array:
**[test, usera, test, userb, test, userc, test, userd]**

And this JSON:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "email": "testusera@abc.com",
        "mobile": "9881880455",
        "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
        "city": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
        "email": "testusera@abc.com",
        "mobile": "9881880455",
        "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
        "city": "Mumbai"
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying to add key-value pairs into existing objects i.e "lastname":"value from array"

```
for(var i=0; i<importedJson.data.length;i++)
{
    for(var f=1;f<=arrFirstLast.length-1;f+2)
    {
       importedJson.data[i].lastName = arrFirstLast[f];
    }
}
```

Expected Json:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "lastname": "usera",
        "email": "testusera@abc.com",
        "mobile": "9881880455",
        "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
        "city": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
        "lastname": "userb",
        "email": "testusera@abc.com",
        "mobile": "9881880455",
        "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
        "city": "Mumbai"
    }
]
}
```

I'm getting Undefined? or no ouput?

Comment: nope. it's inserting an element of the same index everywhere.

Comment: Can you please create jsfeddle

Comment: Please add "arrFirstLast" json also so will create demo

Comment: The mentioned array is the arrFirstLast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felt like my solution is the simplest one among the answers provided

```
var j=0, k=0;
for(var i=0; i<importedJson.data.length;i++)
{
    importedJson.data[i].firstName = arrFirstLast[k];
    k=k+2;
    j=j+1;
    importedJson.data[i].lastName = arrFirstLast[j];
    j=j+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider an array method with only one iterator and a test if the index is inside the array.

```js
var arrFirstLast = ['test', 'usera', 'test', 'userb', 'test', 'userc', 'test', 'userd'],
    importedJson = {
        "data": [
            {
                "email": "testusera@abc.com",
                "mobile": "9881880455",
                "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
                "city": "Mumbai"
            }, {
                "email": "testusera@abc.com",
                "mobile": "9881880455",
                "panCardNo": "ABCD014141",
                "city": "Mumbai"
            }
        ]
    };    

importedJson.data.some(function (a, i) {
    var p = i * 2 + 1;
    if (p < arrFirstLast.length) {
        a.lastName = arrFirstLast[p];
    } else {
        return true; // stop iteration
    }
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(importedJson, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript concat function for to merge array here is the more information about the function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp